# Remapping a key for XKB

Tags: keyboard, xkb

I'm trying to remap the Scroll Lock key so it produces the keycode of any of the Windows keys.

First of all, I dump the current keymap:

`xkbcomp $DISPLAY original-dump`

Then find the keycodes of the keys I'm interested in:

```
cat original-dump | grep SCLK
 <SCLK> = 78;

 cat original-dump | grep LWIN
 <LWIN> = 133;
```

Now I print the component names into a file:

```
setxkbmap -print > original-components
```

Edit the file to add my keycode modification:

```
    xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { 
        include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" 
        // Remap Scroll-lock to the keycode of LWIN(133)
        <SCLK> = 133;
    };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
    };
```

Saved the file above as modified-components and run:

```
xkbcomp modified-components $DISPLAY
```

Dump again:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY original-dump
```

Check the keycodes:

```
cat another-dump | grep SCLK
<SCLK> = 133;
```

So far so good, but when I run `xev`, the keycode of the Scroll Lock key is still **78**.

If I run:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 78 = Super_L"
```

[xev](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xev.1.html) still shows me **78**, but at least the shortcuts that I created in XFCE for the LWIN and RWIN work.

I would like to know what am I doing wrong with [xkb](https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450). Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Tried the following new approach (with success)

Created a new file named `sclkfile` in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory, and added the following contents:

```
 // Make the Scroll Lock key a left Super.
xkb_symbols "sclk_super" {
    replace key <SCLK> { [ Super_L ] };
    modifier_map  Mod4 { <SCLK> };
};
```

Added the new rule in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev`:

```
sclkoption:sclk_super = +sclkfile(sclk_super)
```

And descriptions of the rule in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`:

```
! option
sclkoption           Scroll Lock behaviour
sclkoption:sclk_super Scroll Lock is Super
```

Here too `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`:

```
<configItem>
        <name>sclkoption</name>
        <description>Scroll Lock behaviour</description>
</configItem>    
<option>
    <configItem>
        <name>sclkoption:sclk_super</name>
        <description>Scroll Lock is Super</description>
    </configItem>
</option>
```

Finally run:

```
$ setxkbmap -option sclkoption:sclk_super
```

No errors, and when I print the components of my layout:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+sclkfile(sclk_super)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

The new rule is there.

Now, if I run `xev`:

```
keycode 78 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_R)
```

The keycode is still 78 but the keysym is Super_R. **Success**.

Comment: This is awesome. Finally a proper modern solution. … But my `rules/evdev` specifically states “do not edit”. As it is 1. part of the `xkb-data` package, installed via package manager, and will be overwritten, and 2. it is auto-generated from `rules/*.part` (probably inside the make script of that package). … Can this be done without changing any existing files? (Like a `file` is traditionally accompanied by a `file.d` directory to put such stuff in.)

Comment: Apparently, such stuff goes in `/etc/X11/xkb/`. But how? Apart from straight-up reading the code or specification, `xkb`’s documentation is sadly, lacking, to say the least.

Comment: Scroll Lock _is_ Super. Scroll Lock is the best!